# Trying to solve ordinary Differential Equation using DSolve in wolfram Mathematica. The results are inconsistent with the expected ones

Tags: differential-equations

I have a differential equation from one of the research articles as

$$
   \omega^{2}.L.C\frac{d^2v(x)}{dx^2}+v(x)-V_{cc}+V_{R}\sin(x+\phi)=0
   $$

Whose General solution is given in the normalized form as 
  $$
   \frac{v(x)}{V_{cc}}=C_1\cos qx+C_2\sin qx+1+ \frac{q^2}{1-q^2}.\frac{V_R}{V_{cc}}\sin (x+\phi)
  $$

Whereas

$$
  q=\frac{1}{\omega\sqrt{LC}}
  $$

I am solving the equation using DSolve in Wolfram Mathematica but the results that I obtain in Mathematica do not match the general solution given above. The complete notebook code that I use in Mathematica to solve it is given below

```
Clear[x,y]
A= w^2L.C
b= Vcc
c= VR
q= 1/(w Sqrt[L.C])
eqn=Ay''[x]+y[x]-b+cSin[x+phi]==0
sol=DSolve[eqn,y,x]
simpsol=Simplify[DSolve[eqn,y[x],x]]
```

The output that I obtain is as follows

$$
   v(x)=\frac{\omega(-V_{cc}-C_1\cos qx+V_R \sin (\phi+x)-C_2\sin qx)+\omega^2LC(V_{cc}+C_1\cos qx+C_2\sin qx))}{\omega(\frac{1}{q^2}-1)}
   $$

unpacking the above I get

$$
   v(x)=-\begin{bmatrix}\frac{q^2}{1-q^2} \end{bmatrix}.V_{cc}-\begin{bmatrix}\frac{q^2}{1-q^2} \end{bmatrix}C_1\cos qx+V_R\begin{bmatrix}\frac{q^2}{1-q^2} \end{bmatrix}\sin (\phi +x)-\begin{bmatrix}\frac{q^2}{1-q^2} \end{bmatrix}\sin qx+\frac{1}{\omega(1-q^2)}V_{cc}+\frac{1}{\omega(1-q^2)}C_1\cos qx+\frac{1}{\omega(1-q^2)}C_2\sin qx
   $$

The above equation can further be rearranged as follows

$$
   v(x)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-\omega q^2}{\omega (1-q^2)} \end{bmatrix}V_{cc}+\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-\omega q^2}{\omega (1-q^2)} \end{bmatrix}C_1\cos qx+ \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-\omega q^2}{\omega (1-q^2)} \end{bmatrix}C_2 \sin qx+\frac{V_Rq^2}{1-q^2}\sin (\phi +x)
   $$

which is a lot different from what research article presented (also given above):

$$
   \frac{v(x)}{V_{cc}}=C_1\cos qx+C_2\sin qx+1+ \frac{q^2}{1-q^2}.\frac{V_R}{V_{cc}}\sin (x+\phi)
   $$
There is an extra coefficient present with certain terms

$$
   \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-\omega q^2}{\omega (1-q^2)} \end{bmatrix}
   $$

where did I go wrong, how can I get the same answer?  Thanking you.

Comment: Maybe in research article general solution is wrong or mistake?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have also done hand calculations and the results obtained coincide with that of the research article. Moreover, it is an IEEE transaction article, the result cannot be wrong!.

Comment: @Liyaqat, "it is an IEEE transaction article, the result cannot be wrong!" - you have too much faith in journals; there's a reason why they publish errata from time to time. More to the point: in the first place, **you should have linked to the article you mention in your question**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few typos in your code. a times b is a*b in Mathematica code, a.b is matrix multiplication.
With `C L w^2 == 1/q^2` equation is

```
eqn = -Vcc + VR Sin[phi + x] + y[x] + 1/q^2 (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0

ysol = y /. First@DSolve[eqn, y, x] // Simplify
```

Multiply C[i] with Vcc to get the solution in the textbook.

```
 ysol[x]/Vcc /. {C[1] -> c1*Vcc, C[2] -> c2*Vcc} // FullSimplify

(*   1 + c1 Cos[q x] + c2 Sin[q x] 
   + (q^2 VR Sin[phi + x])/(Vcc - q^2 Vcc)   *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I got the correct results by making corrections suggested by you.

Comment: @J. M.'s technical difficulties   Thank you for your response. I apologize for not linking the research article in my question post. I shall be mindful in the future. In Academia, we generally trust genuine research platforms and take the problem to the next level.